# How to read and modify an xml file using vb.net and linq

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq

I am able to only read and edit the first claim, however I need the code to do the same in all claims. It has to count line in each claim and write a line number in each line. Below is the xml file;

```
<ClaimBatch>
  <Claims>
    <Claim>
      <claimGross>4947.7200</claimGross>
      <numLines>2</numLines>
      <Line>
        <lineNo>1</lineNo>
        <benefitAmount>2473.8600</benefitAmount>
        <levy>247.3860</levy>
      </Line>
      <Line>
        <lineNo>2</lineNo>
        <benefitAmount>2473.8600</benefitAmount>
        <levy>247.3860</levy>
      </Line>
    </Claim>
    <Claim>
      <claimGross>549.6800</claimGross>
      <numLines>2</numLines>
      <Line>
        <benefitAmount>274.8400</benefitAmount>
        <levy>48.0976</levy>
      </Line>
      <Line>
        <benefitAmount>274.8400</benefitAmount>
        <levy>48.0976</levy>
      </Line>
    </Claim>
  </Claims>
</ClaimBatch>
```

Below is the code that I have used so far;

```
Public Sub writeLineNo()

Dim counter As Integer = 1
    Dim reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create("C:\SQLQUERIS\" & cmbschemetxt & " " & dateStr & ".xml")
    xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("C:\SQLQUERIS\" & cmbschemetxt & " " & dateStr & ".xml")

    For Each line In xmlDoc.<ClaimBatch>.<Claims>.<Claim>.<Line>
        If reader.ReadToFollowing("Line") Then
            reader.MoveToContent()
            While reader.ReadToNextSibling("Line")
                line.AddFirst(<lineNo><%= counter %></lineNo>)
                counter += 1
            End While
        End If
    Next
    reader.Close()
    xmlDoc.Save("C:\SQLQUERIS\" & cmbschemetxt & " " & dateStr & ".xml")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use two `For Each` loops. One to loop over each `<Claim>`, and one to loop over each `<line>` inside each `<Claim>`.

Given the following XML

```
Dim xml = <ClaimBatch>
            <Claims>
                <Claim>
                    <claimGross>4947.7200</claimGross>
                    <numLines>2</numLines>
                    <Line>
                        <benefitAmount>2473.8600</benefitAmount>
                        <levy>247.3860</levy>
                    </Line>
                    <Line>
                        <benefitAmount>2473.8600</benefitAmount>
                        <levy>247.3860</levy>
                    </Line>
                </Claim>
                <Claim>
                    <claimGross>549.6800</claimGross>
                    <numLines>2</numLines>
                    <Line>
                        <benefitAmount>274.8400</benefitAmount>
                        <levy>48.0976</levy>
                    </Line>
                    <Line>
                        <benefitAmount>274.8400</benefitAmount>
                        <levy>48.0976</levy>
                    </Line>
                </Claim>
            </Claims>
            </ClaimBatch>
```

use a nested loop like:

```
For Each claim in xml.<Claims>.<Claim>
    Dim counter = 1
    For Each line in claim.<Line>
        line.AddFirst(<lineNo><%= counter %></lineNo>)
        counter += 1
    Next
Next
```

`xml` is now:

[image]